# MySQL audit table: hibernate-envers vs Triggers

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, triggers, hibernate-envers

I have a `user` table which I want to `audit`. I'm using *hibernate-envers* for the same. This is what my `user` class looks like:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "profile_pic")
    private String profilePic;
}
```

I'm not sure about hibernate-enver's performance. Before hibernate-envers, I was using triggers to keep an audit trail. Should I continue with envers or switch back to triggers? 

PS: I want a comparison based on performance. Cause using envers literally doesn't require any extra effort, so effort/development-time wise it's the obvious choice.

Answer (score 3):

If it fits the need and does the job, then continue.  Later on if you find it isn't performing up to some standard, you can always change it or report the performance concern and I can look at it.

To your question, no such benchmark exists.  I'd even be weary of such a benchmark if it did because it is most likely misleading anyway.

Typically, developers design audit triggers like you decribed to  be very simple.  In other words, they act as a row-copier and nothing else.  During an insert, update, or delete, they simply copy a snapshot of the data from the table into another.  Done.

Obviously Envers takes this farther by supporting the notion of audited relationships between entities.  It also allows you to provide it attributes about the environment during a change so you can track things like who changed what, why it was changed, etc.

The biggest advantage of Envers is in fact the effort required to get such a framework working.  As you've indicated, its effortless and even in the most complex of entity relationships, its super simple to manage those.

I'm sure there are use cases where a database trigger will perform equally or better than any client software-based solution.  In that case you have no network latency and the trigger can also use proprietary database options to improve performance where-as a framework will use more cross-platform database agnostic features.

Lastly, your entity you've shown seems to be super simple.  There would literally be little to no overhead for Envers to handle that entity.  There are no relationships and thus it would be a simple insert for each `User` row change and one for the revision entity.

There are implementations of Envers that use far more complex entity object graphs with inheritance and complex associations just fine.